# Handle generic API call in different reducers

Tags: redux, react-router-redux

I have an entity called `client` and another one called `person`.
`client` has a personId for it's main person and we also have a list of people that relates to this `client` in some way. Something like the following:

```
client: {
  clientId: 1
  personId: 1
  people: [{personId: 2}, {personId: 3}]
}
```

Suppose we have an action called `REQUEST_PERSON`, which dispatches `RECEIVE_PERSON` when finished, and two routes within `react-router-redux`, `client/:clientId/` and `client/:clientId/people/:personId` that need to fetch the person info..

I have two reducers, one for the first route and the other for the second one. If I listen to `RECEIVE_PERSON` in both of them, they will always update their state, even when the action was not meant for them.

Should I have two different actions for each situation, like `REQUEST_CLIENT_PERSON/RECEIVE_CLIENT_PERSON` and `REQUEST_PERSON/RECEIVE_PERSON` that will call the same API route? Can I somehow avoid this duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes, you should have two different actions. Having two different reducers listen for the same action type is very rarely something you want to do. I say rarely because there might be a case, but I've never run into one.

The longer answer involves how to do that without repeating yourself. If you find that your reducers and actions are doing the same things and you've duplicated all the code, it would be worth setting up a higher order reducer [as explained in the redux documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ReusingReducerLogic.html).

Comment: Thank you very much, the higher order reducer seems to be exactly what I needed.